# How to copyright an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am currently building an iPhone app that I plan to submit to the App Store in a few weeks. I have read over the internet that apple only accepts apps that are copyrighted. Is that correct?
Does anyone know what exactly I have to do to make my application copyrighted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing the point is that you can only submit content thats copyright belongs to you or that you have the permission to use from a copyright holder.

Unless you release your work to the public domain, you will by default own copyright of any content you create in most jurisdictions.

Answer (score 0):

**No need to explicitely copyright your app**.

What you may have read is that you **need to sign it (CodeSigning) using a certificate**; but that's the standard process you have after obtaning a certificate and a provisionning profile from Apple's Developer Portal (read the doc and tutorials on developer.apple.com).

**Codesigning is not related to "copyrighting"** (in the legal sense of the term). Codesigning your app only ensures that your app code can't be modified/hacked (if the code is modified the signature will become invalid and the app detected as modified) and if published by you (and not someone that fakes your identity)

---

*Of course, aside from that, like in any publication anywhere in the world in any context, you're not allowed to use content copyrighted by others without their conscent (like using an icon in your app that you stole from a website or from another website if it has copyrighted this icon/image).*